# Selecting same column values from two tables

Tags: mysql

I am doing one project on struts in which i want to compare two table's row values and want to get matched columns as result set and from result set i want to take out no of matched columns. I am doing the following coding but i always gets 3 as columnsNumber. Please help me to get exact result.

```
public class ResultDAO {


 public int correctAnswer() throws Exception {

     int columnsNumber=0;

     Connection con=null;       
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

     ResultSet rs = null;
     String query="SELECT DISTINCT q1,q2,q3 FROM test WHERE (q1,q2,q3)  IN (SELECT q1,q2,q3 FROM result)ORDER BY q1,q2,q3 ASC";
     try {

         con=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();

         pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

         rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

         ResultSetMetaData rsmd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();

         columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
         System.out.println(columnsNumber);


    } 
     catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("exception in DAO");
    }
    return columnsNumber;


 }
}
```

**Table1**: test

columns: id, q1, q2, q3 values : 1,A,C,C

**Table2**: result

columns: id, q1, q2, q3 values : 1,A,B,C

I am using this code but getting value as null

public class ResultDAO {

```
 public String correctAnswer() throws Exception {

     String columnsNumber = null;

     Connection con=null;       
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

     ResultSet rs = null;
     String query="SELECT test.id,IF (test.q1 = result.q1, test.q1, NULL) as q1,IF (test.q2 = result.q2, test.q2, NULL) as q2,IF (test.q3 = result.q3, test.q3, NULL) as q3,(test.q1 = result.q1) + (test.q2 = result.q2) + (test.q3 = result.q3) as matchedColumns FROM test INNER JOIN result USING (id) ORDER BY q1,q2,q3";
     try {

         con=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();

         pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

         rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

         System.out.println(rs.next());
         while(rs.next()){
        columnsNumber=rs.getString("matchedColumns");


         }
         System.out.println(columnsNumber);


    } 
     catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("exception in DAO");
    }
    return columnsNumber;


 }
```

}

Comment: Is there foreign key constrains between tables

Comment: you're selecting 3 columns so you'll always have 3 as column count, shouldn't you be getting row count instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e59fa/2/0)

```
SELECT test.id,
       IF (test.q1 = result.q1, test.q1, NULL) as q1,
       IF (test.q2 = result.q2, test.q2, NULL) as q2,
       IF (test.q3 = result.q3, test.q3, NULL) as q3,
       (test.q1 = result.q1) + (test.q2 = result.q2) + (test.q3 = result.q3) as matchedColumns
FROM test
INNER JOIN result
USING (id)
ORDER BY q1,q2,q3
```

edit: to get unmatched columns, just change the `=` sign to `!=` like this and add another created column named unmatchedColumns [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e59fa/7/0)

```
SELECT test.id,
       IF (test.q1 = result.q1, test.q1, NULL) as q1,
       IF (test.q2 = result.q2, test.q2, NULL) as q2,
       IF (test.q3 = result.q3, test.q3, NULL) as q3,
       (test.q1 = result.q1) + (test.q2 = result.q2) + (test.q3 = result.q3) as matchedColumns,
       (test.q1 != result.q1) + (test.q2 != result.q2) + (test.q3 != result.q3) as unmatchedColumns
FROM test
INNER JOIN result
USING (id)
ORDER BY q1,q2,q3
```

Comment: there is no reslut from  this query : 0 rows fetched

Comment: did you try the sqlFiddle? and see the result?

Comment: well according to your data, you should see 1 row. I don't know why you're getting 0 rows. When i run your query in your code i get 0 rows

Comment: i just tried sqlfiddle in that i got matchedcolumn value as 2, is this query is creating a coulmn named matchedcolumn or its just showing result

Comment: no the query is creating that column by comparing each column in test with each column in result, you can rename it to whatever you like it's the last item on the SELECT list.

Comment: in my sqlFiddle example I have 2 ids, id 1 has 2 matchedColumns and id 2 has only 1 matchedColumns, does that make sense?

Comment: but how can i get matchedcolumn value from resultset

Comment: i am not familiar with struts but you could try `rsmd.getString(5)` or `rsmd.getString(4)` depending on if it starts counting columns from 0 or 1 or maybe just `rs.getString(5)` not too sure

Comment: i m getting Exception

Comment: which one did you try? or did all three different ones give you exception? According to this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/550490/Struts/Result-sets-struts) rs.getString(4) or rs.getString(5) should work, maybe you have to call rs.next(). and put it in a while loop like the code on the link says

Comment: i used rs.getString(5) but without while loop ohk let me try with while loop

Comment: rs.next value is true, but in while loop when i am getting rs.getString as null

Comment: rs.next is true but ...?

Comment: try rs.getString(4) and see what you get

Comment: if you get the count then you know it must be starting column counting from 0 and not 1

Comment: rs.getString(4) is also giving null

Comment: did you get some rows returned when you ran it on your database (mysql query browser)?

Comment: ya i got matchedcolumn there

Comment: try `rs.getString("matchedColumns")`

Comment: can we chat actually in comment section there is word limit so i m not able to provide you the code i m using

Comment: i tried clicking on chat but it says that you don't have enough reputation to chat

Comment: I was trying to help this other person and they had this cool app that let me see his screen and control it too it was pretty cool I think It's called MilsoftConnect or something

Comment: i cant provide answer too due to low reputation

Comment: really i thought anyone can answer!

Comment: remove the `System.out.println(rs.next())` because that will move it to the next row and it'll never hit the while loop

Comment: move the `System.out.println(columnsNumber);` into the while loop just before you close it to print output if there are multiple rows

Comment: after you've done the above, you can go back and try using `rs.getString(4)` or `rs.getString(5)` and such.

Comment: CAN I GET UNMATCHED COLUMNS TOO PLEASE PROVIDE THE QUERY @TIN TRAN

Comment: The unmatched columns are the ones with NULL values, or do you mean a count of unmatched columns?

Comment: ya but can we get it separately in another column like we get matched as matchedColumns

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming    id is foreign key in result table

```
 select tst.id,tst.q1,tst.q2,tst.q3,
    r.id,r.q1,r.q2,r.q3
     from test as tst
    LEFT JOIN result AS r
    ON tst.id = r.id
```

Comment: manish there is no foreign key is it required, actually i dont want to do anything with id i just want q1 and q2 in result and count as 2

Comment: if both tables are related than required

Comment: both the id columns are primary keys in thier respective tables,primary key of one table is the foreign key for other i think